# Soup works on one IMBD page but not on another. How to solve?

Tags: python, html, web, beautifulsoup, web-crawler

```
url1 = "https://www.imdb.com/user/ur34087578/watchlist"
url = "https://www.imdb.com/search/title/?groups=top_1000&ref_=adv_prv"

results1 = requests.get(url1, headers=headers)
results = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
soup1 = BeautifulSoup(results1.text, "html.parser")
soup = BeautifulSoup(results.text, "html.parser")

movie_div1 = soup1.find_all('div', class_='lister-item-content')
movie_div = soup.find_all('div', class_='lister-item mode-advanced')
#using unique tag for each movie in the respective link

print(movie_div1)
#empty list
print(movie_div)
#gives perfect list
```

Why is movie_div1 giving an empty list? I am not able to identify any difference in the URL structures to indicate the code should be different. All leads appreciated.

Comment: What are you trying to extract from your watchlist? I can't even find the `div` tag with the class `lister-item-content` when I open the webpage in my web browser.

Comment: @ritiek did you open inspect and then try searching?

Comment: Yup, it shows up on inspect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately the div you want is processed by a javascript code so you can't get by **scraping** the raw html request.

You can get the movies you want by the request json your browser gets, which you won't need to **scrape** the code with beautifulsoup, making your script much faster.

2nd option is using Selenium.

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

As @SakuraFreak mentioned, you could parse the JSON received. However, this JSON response is embedded within the HTML itself which is later converted to HTML by browser JS (this is what you see as `<div class="lister-item-content">...</div>`.

For example, this is how you would extract the JSON content from the HTML to display movie/show names from the watchlist:

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import json

url = "https://www.imdb.com/user/ur34087578/watchlist"
response = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, "html.parser")

details = str(soup.find('span', class_='ab_widget'))

json_initial = "IMDbReactInitialState.push("
json_leftover = ");\n"

json_start = details.find(json_initial) + len(json_initial)
details = details[json_start:]
json_end = details.find(json_leftover)

json_data = json.loads(details[:json_end])

imdb_titles = json_data["titles"]
for item in imdb_titles.values():
    print(item["primary"]["title"])
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for spending your time to come up with a solution, really. I just have a small doubt. In your loop, you directly extracted the "titles" without explicitly defining where they are located (Previously in the normal "HTML" I had to specify the class..h3..tag..unique identifier and so on to get the position). Additionally, when I search "title" in the inspect, i am getting this block of javascript (https://imgur.com/a/1CiGCOq). Did you look through the print of soup to locate the tag for the movie names?

Comment: Yup, the JSON content you see in the image you posted is exactly what the code extracts from the webpage response content received. It then converts this extracted JSON content to a python dictionary (by calling `json.loads`), and then indexes the value of "titles" from this dictionary (which further contains relevant information about the shows/movies from your IMDB watchlist). So, the above extracting or indexing the value of "titles" is not on a BeautifulSoup object (which I think you think) but is on a python dictionary which is a bit different. Yup, I looked at the output of soup.